# What's the difference between an Unreakable Vow and a blood pact?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, unbreakable-vow

I recently re-watched *Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grinderwald* and had a major question. In the movie Albus Dumbledore has a flashback when he was a young adult

> with Gellert Grindelwald. The men make a blood pact which later we find out according to Dumbledore is why he couldn't move against his friend.

In *The Half Blood Prince* we see a similar agreement (the Unbreakable Vow) being drawn between

> Severus Snape and Narcissa Malfoy which is to protect Draco Malfoy and kill Dumbledore if necessary.

What are the main differences between the two agreements and what is the extent of their power?

Comment: There's been some controversy about what kind of pact did they have exactly and how it is similar to Unbreakable Vow, but before future movies address this issue, the clear answer does not exist, we can only speculate on this.

Comment: I'm tempted to say the difference is that you can break an Unbreakable Vow (albeit at a high cost), whereas a Blood Pact physically prevents either party from breaking the terms of the pact i.e. Dumbledore and Grindelwald are literally prevented from fighting, even if they were to meet. As @Nikita Neganov says though, it's all speculation until more is revealed about them. One thing we can be certain of is there will be a way around the pact, or a way to nullify it, as they are going to duel each other eventually.

Comment: One involves a macguffin and the other doesn't

Answer (score 4):

As of now we can only speculate about the difference. Here are the obvious ones:

**Blood pact:**

- Seems to prohibit Dumbledore from personally challenge or fight Grindlewald
- Does not prevent him to send somebody else to do this.
- Seems that it is able to break it by breaking / destroying the vessel containing the blood (at least this is pointed at in the last conversation between Dumbledore and Newt)

**Unbreakable Vow:**

- seems to value intend rather than real action (I don't think that Dumbledore could send someone after Grindlewald if it had been a unbreakable vow, but that is just my opinion)
- can not be broken (or you will die)

These are only assumptions, don't have concrete quotes from Movies / Books to substantiate them.